# Proof that the probability of one RV being larger than $n-1$ others is $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: probability, distributions, proof

This is a follow-on from my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132949/the-probability-of-a-random-variable-being-larger-than-a-sequence-of-random-valu) about samples from a distribution.

Suppose $X_1 \ldots X_{n-1}, X_n$ are random variables all following some fixed distribution $D$. How do I prove that $P(X_n > X_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge X_n > X_{n-1}) = \frac{1}{n}$ (this is true intuitively and experimentally).

Comment: This is not necessarily true. If $X_i = 1$ identically then what you're trying to prove is false.

Comment: you need to put more assumptions on the distribution $D$.

Comment: One might try to assume the $X_i$ are independent and $D$ is continuous, but even this will not suffice. Take, for instance, *negative* random variables and let $n$ be any odd number.  Then the product $X_1\cdots X_{n-1}$ must be positive, whence $\Pr(X_n\gt X_1\cdots X_{n-1})=0$. Is it possible you meant something other than a product where you wrote "$X_1\ldots X_{n-1}$"? If this is intended as a shorthand for "$X_n\gt X_1$ and $X_n\gt X_2$ and ... and $X_n\gt X_{n-1}$," then ask @Glen_b to post his comment to your previous question as an answer, because it will serve just fine.

Comment: Looking at the OP's other question, it appears that he does not mean the product but just a collection, and whether $X_n$ is larger than the maximum of the $n-1$ collection. But it obviously created confusion here.

Comment: REFlint -- for continuous D, in which ways do you feel the symmetry argument outlined in my comment starting "Easy..." on your other question would fall short of a proof? Perhaps we would be able to provide you with some reassurance or details on what you feel it lacks.

Comment: Thanks for picking that up Alecos, bad notation! I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a slightly more notational proof, since sometimes people feel squeamish about intuitive proofs like [glen_b's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132949/the-probability-of-a-random-variable-being-larger-than-a-sequence-of-random-valu#comment252600_132949). (Sometimes for good reason, since it's not necessarily immediately obvious that his proof doesn't apply to discrete distributions.)

Suppose that $X_i$ are distributed iid according to some distribution $D$.
Let $M_i$ be the event that $X_i = \max(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.
Clearly, at least one of the $M_i$ must hold, so
$\Pr(M_1 \cup \dots \cup M_n) = 1$.
But, using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)
\begin{align*}
\Pr(M_1 \cup \dots \cup M_n)
&= \sum_i Pr(M_i) - \sum_{i < j} \Pr(M_i \cap M_j) + \sum_{i < j < k} \Pr(M_i \cap M_j \cap M_k) - \dots
\end{align*}
If $D$ is continuous, then $\Pr(M_i \cap M_j) = 0$ for all $i \ne j$; all the latter terms drop. Also, since the $X_i$ are identically distributed clearly $\Pr(M_1) = \Pr(M_i)$ for all $i$. Thus
$$ \Pr(M_1 \cup \dots \cup M_n) = \sum_i \Pr(M_i) = n \Pr(M_1) = 1,$$
so $\Pr(M_1) = \frac{1}{n}$.

If $D$ is not continuous, the higher terms don't drop out. Taking [@Yair Daon's example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133616/proof-that-the-probability-of-one-rv-being-larger-than-n-1-others-is-frac1#comment254216_133616) where $X_i$ is identically 1, every $M_i$ always holds, and the sum becomes
$$
\Pr(M_1 \cup \dots \cup M_n) = \sum_i 1 - \sum_{i<j} 1 + \sum_{i<j<k} 1 - \dots
= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k} = 1
.$$

Comment: +1 This is definitely the easy and insightful way to *see* why the result is true, and your rigor is helpful.

Comment: Starting from $\sum_i\Pr(M_i)=1$, we have that the _average value_ of these $n$ probabilities is $\frac 1n$. Now, without loss of generality, suppose that there exists a proof that $\Pr(M_1)>\frac 1n$. Then, by interchanging subscripts $1$ and $i$ in the proof, we can show that $\Pr(M_i)>\frac 1n$ and similarly $\Pr(M_j)>\frac 1n$ and $\ldots$, leading to the conclusion that we are either in Lake Wobegon where _all_ the $\Pr(M_j)$ are above average in value, or that the proof that $\Pr(M_1)>\frac 1n$ is faulty, and that all the $\Pr(M_i)$ must necessarily have the same value $\frac 1n$.

Answer (score 8):

For absolutely continuous random variables, this has a nice-looking proof.

We have an i.i.d. sample characterized by density $f$ and distribution function $F$. To avoid subscripts, denote $Y \equiv X_{(n-1)}$ the maximum of the subsample of size $n-1$, and $W \equiv X_n$ the $n$-th draw. Being the maximum order statistic, the density function of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = (n-1)f(y)[F(y)]^{n-2}$. We want to calculate the probability that the $n$-th draw will be maximum (we do not know the values of any draw),

$$P(Y \leq W) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^w f_{WY}(w,y){\rm d}y{\rm d}w$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^w f(w) f_Y(y){\rm d}y{\rm d}w$$

the decomposition of the joint density due to independence. $f_Y(y)$ is not a simple density, so we change the order of integration

$$P(Y \leq W) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)\int_y^{\infty} f(w) {\rm d}w{\rm d}y$$  $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)[1-F(y)] {\rm d}y = 1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(y)F(y) {\rm d}y$$

since we have integrated the density of $Y$ over the whole support. Writing out this density for the remaining integral we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(y)F(y) {\rm d}y = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n-1)f(y)[F(y)]^{n-2}F(y){\rm d}y $$

$$=\frac {n-1}{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}nf(y)[F(y)]^{n-1}{\rm d}y = \frac {n-1}{n}$$

since the integrand has become the density function of the maximum order statistic from a sample of size $n$, and so integrated over the whole support, equals unity too.

So,

$$P(Y \leq W) = 1- \frac {n-1}{n} = \frac 1n$$

Answer (score 4):

Assume that these are continuous random variables then you'll be right on the money. Obviously they must be independent, i.e. i.i.d. in this case.

Think of how many permutations are of the sequence $X_1,\dots,X_n$, where the maximum will end up being at the last position? It's $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!n!}$. There are $n!$ permutations in total. So, your probability is $\frac{1}{n}$.

For discrete probabilities your claim will not be right, as @YairDaon showed you